# Live Stream Video Simultaneously on Facebook and Youtube

Tags: android, facebook, youtube, stream, live

I want to make android app that can stream live videos directly to Facebook and YouTube using their API. I have done live stream video on both but individually (one at a time). But i want to **stream live videos to both (Facebook-YouTube) at same time** from phone camera.
I am using this library as RTMP Publisher - https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java.
I have tried taking multiple objects but its not working with this.

Comment: how you did that? Im also looking for solution which you are already implemented.

Comment: @ZaidMirza I have done live streaming video one at a time but i want to stream on both fb/youtube at the same time which i am not able to right now

Comment: how you did one at a time? I need it

Comment: Docs are already available for that. I have managed to do so by reference from the docs only

Comment: Are you able to stream on both because when I'm trying to do the same my app screen turns white

Answer (score 1):

I'm rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java developer.

If you want send duplicate stream to different server you only need duplicate srsFlvMuxer or rtspClient depend your stream type.
For example, if you are using rtmpCamera1 you need modify this class that will look like:

```
public class RtmpCamera1 extends Camera1Base {

  private SrsFlvMuxer srsFlvMuxer;
  private SrsFlvMuxer srsFlvMuxer2;

  public RtmpCamera1(SurfaceView surfaceView, ConnectCheckerRtmp connectChecker) {
    super(surfaceView);
    srsFlvMuxer = new SrsFlvMuxer(connectChecker);
    srsFlvMuxer2 = new SrsFlvMuxer(connectChecker);
  }

  public RtmpCamera1(TextureView textureView, ConnectCheckerRtmp connectChecker) {
    super(textureView);
    srsFlvMuxer = new SrsFlvMuxer(connectChecker);
    srsFlvMuxer2 = new SrsFlvMuxer(connectChecker);
  }

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
  public RtmpCamera1(OpenGlView openGlView, ConnectCheckerRtmp connectChecker) {
    super(openGlView);
    srsFlvMuxer = new SrsFlvMuxer(connectChecker);
    srsFlvMuxer2 = new SrsFlvMuxer(connectChecker);
  }

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
  public RtmpCamera1(LightOpenGlView lightOpenGlView, ConnectCheckerRtmp connectChecker) {
    super(lightOpenGlView);
    srsFlvMuxer = new SrsFlvMuxer(connectChecker);
    srsFlvMuxer2 = new SrsFlvMuxer(connectChecker);
  }

  /**
   * H264 profile.
   *
   * @param profileIop Could be ProfileIop.BASELINE or ProfileIop.CONSTRAINED
   */
  public void setProfileIop(byte profileIop) {
    srsFlvMuxer.setProfileIop(profileIop);
    srsFlvMuxer2.setProfileIop(profileIop);
  }

  @Override
  public void setAuthorization(String user, String password) {
    srsFlvMuxer.setAuthorization(user, password);
    srsFlvMuxer2.setAuthorization(user, password);
  }

  @Override
  protected void prepareAudioRtp(boolean isStereo, int sampleRate) {
    srsFlvMuxer.setIsStereo(isStereo);
    srsFlvMuxer.setSampleRate(sampleRate);
    srsFlvMuxer2.setIsStereo(isStereo);
    srsFlvMuxer2.setSampleRate(sampleRate);
  }

  @Override
  protected void startStreamRtp(String url) {
    if (videoEncoder.getRotation() == 90 || videoEncoder.getRotation() == 270) {
      srsFlvMuxer.setVideoResolution(videoEncoder.getHeight(), videoEncoder.getWidth());
      srsFlvMuxer2.setVideoResolution(videoEncoder.getHeight(), videoEncoder.getWidth());
    } else {
      srsFlvMuxer.setVideoResolution(videoEncoder.getWidth(), videoEncoder.getHeight());
      srsFlvMuxer2.setVideoResolution(videoEncoder.getWidth(), videoEncoder.getHeight());
    }
    srsFlvMuxer.start(url);
    //second url stream. For now hardcoded, modify this method to set in startStream library method.
    srsFlvMuxer2.start("rtmp://x.rtmp.youtube.com/xxxxxxxxx");   
  }

  @Override
  protected void stopStreamRtp() {
    srsFlvMuxer.stop();
    srsFlvMuxer2.stop();
  }

  @Override
  protected void getAacDataRtp(ByteBuffer aacBuffer, MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
    srsFlvMuxer.sendAudio(aacBuffer.duplicate(), info); //duplicate because you will reuse it on the second srsFlvMuxer.
    srsFlvMuxer2.sendAudio(aacBuffer, info);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSPSandPPSRtp(ByteBuffer sps, ByteBuffer pps) {
    srsFlvMuxer.setSpsPPs(sps.duplicate(), pps.duplicate());//duplicate because you will reuse it on the second srsFlvMuxer.
    srsFlvMuxer2.setSpsPPs(sps, pps);
  }

  @Override
  protected void getH264DataRtp(ByteBuffer h264Buffer, MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
    srsFlvMuxer.sendVideo(h264Buffer.duplicate(), info);//duplicate because you will reuse it on the second srsFlvMuxer.
    srsFlvMuxer2.sendVideo(h264Buffer, info);
  }
}
```

Comment: what to do with the overridden methods like getSentAudioFrames() that returing some value.
its not working actually.its just giving crash in library.